# Debugging x64 programs locally without being administrator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, 64-bit

For the past several years I have been logging into my PC as a limited user and debugging applications this way. Now that I'm making the move to x64 bit applications, I'm unable to do this and get a dialog error as shown below. Of course this is not the real problem as the service is running just fine. If I log off and log in as admin I can debug normally just like I do for a 32 bit process.

Since x64 debugging is currently making use of remote debugging techniques, does anyone know a way to do this without being administrator?

> VS2008 Error:
>
> > Unable to start program
> >     "C:\PathToDebug\my.exe"
> >     Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) failed
> >     to start. Verify that the remote
> >     debugger is properly installed.

**!!! EDIT !!!**

> > Sorry, I found the error. I use a very secure environment, LUA + SRP, and for some reason an additinal rule must be added for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe" All is good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found the error. I use a very secure environment, LUA + SRP, and for some reason an additional rule must be added for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe" All is good now.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strong possibility that the x64 program was not installed for "all users". When performing the installation, sometimes you see this option before installing the files. This is likely not related to x64 architecture but instead a file permissions error.

When installing applications it's best to install as the ADMIN and enable it for all users first. Then as a limited user there are no file permission errors.